# AWS S3+ Kinesis Live media streaming

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-connect, amazon-kinesis-video-streams, voicemail

I am enabling live media streaming within Amazon Connect to setup voicemail and to store the Customer voice. I am not sure how to store that audio in to an S3 bucket.

My use case is to setup an voicemail for Contact center and store those as object in S3 bucket.

I have enabled the streaming within IVR flows. However, I am not able to get how to access these data frm kinesis video streaming. I have found similar artical but not resolved in the same way I am looking for.